# Svg animation for curved path

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a SVG and want to animate it, and I'm new to animating SVG. So I want the circle to move on top of curved semi-oval, slowly within 5 minutes. Is there possible to animate with CSS?
So far I found this brief explanation [about curve path](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/curved-path-animations-in-css/) but it's not exactly what I want, or I'm not understanding how to implement to my code.
Here is a partial code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Ilima/pen/rvXxJo)
EDIT: I need the dot to move exactly on top of curved line.

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
    margin: 15% auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #212121;
    box-shadow: 0 29px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.50),
                0 25px 22px rgba(0,0,0,0.30),
                inset 0 0 15px 5px rgb(227, 228, 229);
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #9E9E9E;
}
.time-container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 130px 50px rgb(132, 2, 2),
              0px 120px 70px rgb(99, 1, 1);
}
.time{
  font-size: 3rem;
  color : #D50000;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.semi-oval{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="time-container"><p class="time">5:00</p></div>
  <div class="semi-oval">
   <svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <defs>
       <filter id="shadow">
         <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="10" stdDeviation="6"/>
       </filter>
     </defs>
     <path id="path" d="M10 80 Q 95 10 180 80" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" filter="url(#shadow)"/>
     <circle class="circle" cx=15 cy=76 r=7 stroke=#f70202 stroke-width=2 fill=#f92020 />
  </svg>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a way to do that in css `animation` but it would be better if you use javaScript `requestAnimationFrame` method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - Animate object in curved path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949940/css-animate-object-in-curved-path)

Comment: why not use svgs animate? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate

Comment: @soulshined how would I approach this?

Comment: @Adam how would I approach this in JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `animationMotion` element to move the `circle` along  `#path` path. For further info, refer to these two links.

1. [MDN - animationMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion)
2. [CSS-tricks - A Guide to SVG Animations](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15% auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #212121;
  box-shadow: 0 29px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), 0 25px 22px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30), inset 0 0 15px 5px rgb(227, 228, 229);
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #9E9E9E;
}

.time-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 130px 50px rgb(132, 2, 2), 0px 120px 70px rgb(99, 1, 1);
}

.time {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #D50000;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.semi-oval {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="time-container">
    <p class="time">5:00</p>
  </div>
  <div class="semi-oval">
    <svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <defs>
           <filter id="shadow">
             <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="10" stdDeviation="6"/>
           </filter>
         </defs>
         <circle class="circle" cx="0" cy=0 r=7 stroke=#f70202 stroke-width=2 fill=#f92020 >
             <animateMotion dur="100s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto" >
                 <mpath xlink:href="#path"/>
             </animateMotion>
         </circle>
         <path id="path" d="M10 80 Q 95 10 180 80" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" filter="url(#shadow)"/>
      </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

At the moment, animation duration is `100s`, but you can change it.

---

## Update

`AnimationMotion` has an attribute called `begin` that defines when the animation should start. You can use it to define when the circle should start moving along the curve. For further info, visit these two links

1. [MDN - begin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute)
2. [StackOverflow - SVG animation delay on each repetition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690880/svg-animation-delay-on-each-repetition)

Comment: This is great! Solves my problem. I'm curious now, what if I want to animate on the specific time? I'm making sort of a timer project, and I need to animate every time 5 minutes left on the timer. I hope it makes sense. So let's say I have 25 minutes set, and this won't animate, unless it's reaches 5 min. Can I work around with JS or jQuery and manipulate it like a  regular html element?

Comment: @IlimkanOmurzakova Updated the answer.  You can use `jQuery`  or `vanilla JS` to further customise the animation.

Comment: Awesome! This was really helpful 