# how to make curve line using css with animate?

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to create curve line like this using css:
[image]

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to StackOverflow. The main reason your question is getting downvotes is because you haven't added any code that you have tried to write so far. The other thing is, you haven't stated whether you want the curve to move along the line (but that's not a downvote reason, just something you need to clarify.) Here's a good example of a CSS animation question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949940/css-animate-object-in-curved-path

Answer (score 0):

You can try canvas:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(100, 20);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(105, 30, 110, 30, 115, 20);
ctx.lineTo(150, 20);
ctx.stroke();
```

Example code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FW7CGRNXNTWQ